# Simple implementation of Rock, Paper, Scissors game in Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, rock-paper-scissors

This is my first attempt at writing code from scratch.

I'm visually impaired and would like to know if the code is well structured, commented and readable for a collaborator who might read it in the future

It's also available [on GitHub](https://github.com/blindingSlow/myFirstStuff).

```
# Blinding Slow Artsy Stuff
# A simple Rock, Paper Scissors game
# Just trying out things I'm learning about coding

# import libraries
import random, os, time

# String animation
def animaString(string):
    name = string
    nameLength = len(name)
    roll = 0
    while roll <=nameLength :
        os.system("clear")
        print(name[:roll])
        roll += 1
        time.sleep(.05)

# call intro animation
animaString("Blinding Slow Artsy Stuff kinda proudly presents:")

# main game function
def startGame() :

# set initial score
    pOneScore = 0
    pTwoScore = 0

# "tutorial"    
    print("""
Rock, Paper, Scissors...
-------------------------------------
Type a number and press Enter/Return
1 = Rock
2 = Paper
3 = Scissors      
-------------------------------------
    """)

# set hands list
    handList = ("Rock", "Paper", "Scissors")

# validate player choice
    while pOneScore < 3  and pTwoScore < 3:
        pOnePick = input("Choose your hand: ")
        while pOnePick != "1" and pOnePick != "2" and pOnePick != "3" :
                print()
                print("Invalid option! Use 1 for rock, 2 for paper or 3 for scissors.")
                pOnePick = input("Go: ")
                continue

# select hand option from list
        if pOnePick == "1" :
            pOnePick = handList[0]
        elif pOnePick == "2" :
            pOnePick = handList[1]
        elif pOnePick == "3" :
            pOnePick = handList[2]

# pick a random option from list for the computer hand
        pTwoPick = random.choice(handList)

# clear screen and print picked hands to the console
        print()
        os.system("clear")
        print(f"Your hand:      {pOnePick}")
        print(f"Computer hand:  {pTwoPick}")

# set the game winner and increase score
        winner = ""
        if pOnePick == pTwoPick :
            winner = "Draw"
        if pOnePick == "Rock" :
            if pTwoPick == "Paper" :
                pTwoScore += 1
                winner = "Computer"
            if pTwoPick == "Scissors" :
                pOneScore += 1
                winner = "Player"
        if pOnePick == "Paper" :
            if pTwoPick == "Scissors" :
                pTwoScore += 1
                winner = "Computer"
            if pTwoPick == "Rock" :
                pOneScore += 1
                winner = "Player"
        if pOnePick == "Scissors" :
            if pTwoPick == "Rock" :
                pTwoScore += 1
                winner = "Computer"
            if pTwoPick == "Paper" :
                pOneScore += 1
                winner = "Player"

# get game winner and print it to the console
        print()
        if winner == "Player" :
            print("You won!")
        elif winner == "Computer" :
            print("Computer won!")
        elif winner == "Draw" :
            print("It's a draw!")
        
# print the new score
        print()
        print(f"""Match Score (Best of 3):
You:       {pOneScore}
Computer:  {pTwoScore}""")
        print()

# check if there is a match winner        
        if pOneScore == 3 :
            print()
            print("You are the match winner!!!")
        if pTwoScore == 3 :
            print()
            print("Computer is the match winner!")

# reset or quit function        
    def again() :

# get and validate player choice        
        print()
        resetGame = input("Play again! Yes or No?")
        while resetGame != "y" and resetGame != "n" :
            print("Invalid option! Use 'y' for YES or 'n' for NO")
            resetGame = input("Let's play again? ")
            continue

# if YES, clear screen and reset game
        if resetGame == "y" :
            os.system("clear")
            startGame()

# if NO, print animated quiting messages and exit game
        if resetGame == "n" :
            animaString("""Blinding Slow Artsy Stuff kinda thank you for playing...
...seriously though, thanks!""")
            time.sleep(1)
            animaString("contact me! github.com/blindingslow")
            time.sleep(5)
            animaString("Goodbye!!!")
            time.sleep(2)
            os.system("clear")
            exit()

# call reset or quit function
    again()

# call main game function
startGame()
```

Comment: Good job on the 3-way game. And now here is your next 5-way assignment: https://www.wikihow.com/Play-Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock

Answer (score 3):

A few things, as python syntax is based on spacing, having comments not in line with the corresponding lines is jarring. Instead of

```
# if YES, clear screen and reset game
        if resetGame == "y" :
```

have

```
        # if YES, clear screen and reset game
        if resetGame == "y" :
```

Since you've already validated input is 1, 2, or 3 (string) casting to int would make `pOnePick = handList[0]` (and the surrounding `if...elif`) shorter to just `pOnePick = handList[int(pOnePick) - 1]`

When you check `set the game winner and increase score` making these into `if...elif` would add clarity easily showing that both score and winner are set somewhere in the chain and further checks wouldn't be necessary.

When you prompt the user for input `resetGame = input("Play again! Yes or No?")` you don't indicate what you want the user to enter as input initially (y or n), adding to the prompt would help `resetGame = input("Play again! Yes(y) or No(n)?")`

A security risk is having your email in plain text on a public page. Internet trolls/bots harvest email addresses in a variety of methods for a variety of reasons that don't do you any good. Some people post in the format `my_email at domain dot com` (but as this is a common practice, IDK how well this actually protects you)

Answer (score 2):

## PEP 8

The [Style Guide for Python Coders](https://pep8.org/) has many guidelines all Python programmers should follow, to help make all Python code more readable.

### Naming

Variables and function names should be `snake_case`, not the much harder to read `bumpyWords`.  This means `animaString` should be `animate_string` and `nameLength` should be `name_length`.

### White Space

[depperm](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/282821/100620) covered a few whitespace points.  Here are a few more:

- Binary operators should have a space on either side, so `roll <=nameLength` should be `roll <= name_length`
- There should be no space before colons at the end of `def`, `if` and `while` statements.

### Code organization

Structure your file as ...

- imports
- constant declarations
- class & function declarations
- mainline code

Your code starts off with imports, and then defines the `animaString` function, then it runs some mainline code `animaString("Blinding Slow ...")`, then it goes back to defining the `startGame` function, and finally more mainline code `startGame()`.  Finding all the places where mainline code is sprinkled into the file makes reading the code harder.

## Clearing the Screen

`os.system("clear")` is not portable (it doesn't work on Windows), and it is "expensive" as it has to spawn a new process to launch a new program whose only job is to clear the screen.

For a much lighter-weight alternative, use an ANSI escape sequence to clear the screen:

```
def clear_screen():
    print("\033[2J", end='')
```

If raw ANSI codes are too frightening, use a Python module which defines them for you.  The `colorama` module (`pip install colorama`) provides cross-platform support (Unix **and** Windows), and supports easy coloured, bolded, and/or underlined text, plus cursor movement and other functionalities.

```
import colorama
import colorama.ansi

def clear_screen():
    print(colorama.ansi.clear_screen(), end='')

def main():
    ... your code ...
    clear_screen()
    ... more code ...

try:
    colorama.init()
    main()
finally:
    colorama.deinit()
```

## Naming

`string` is a standard library module name; you can `import string`.  This makes using `string` as a variable name confusing.  `text` would be a better name.

## Unnecessary assignments

`name = string` makes a copy of the object reference in `string`.  Why?  Neither `string` nor `name` is ever changed, so there is no need for the additional variable.

## Loop like a Native

See [talk by Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html).

You don't need to write:

```
    roll = 0
    while roll <= name_length:
        ...
        roll += 1
```

when you can simply write:

```
    for roll in range(0, name_length + 1):
        ...
```

## Avoid Tail Recursion

Python has a finite stack size, and it does not do Tail Recursion Optimization (TRO).  This means when your code executes, you could get the stack ...

- startGame()

  - again()

    - startGame()

      - again()

        - startGame()

          - again()

            - startGame()

              - again()

                - ...

... and eventually end up with `RecursionError`.

Instead, write a function for executing a single round (`play_round()`) which returns the result of the round: win, lose, or draw.  Write another function (`play_match()`) which plays a match, by calling `play_game()` in a loop for each round, and keeps the scores.  When one player reaches a score of 3, the function declares the match winner, and returns.  Write a third function which uses a loop to call `play_match()` and asks the user if they wish to play again.  If the user answers "no", break out of the loop.

## Don't call exit

Never call `exit()`.  This terminates the Python interpreter, destroying all variables, making testing and debugging difficult.

Instead, simply return to the mainline script.  When the mainline script finishes, the program will exit cleanly.

## Expressive Expressions

You have 10 `if` statements, with a lot of redundant code, to determine whether player one or player two wins a round, and update the scores appropriately.  This could be greatly simplified with more expressive code:

```
PLAYER_WINS = {("Rock", "Scissors"), ("Paper", "Rock"), ("Scissors", "Paper")}

...

   if pOnePick == pTwoPick:
       winner = "Draw"
   elif (pOnePick, pTwoPick) in PLAYER_WINS:
       winner = "Player"
       pOneScore += 1
   else:
       winner = "Computer"
       pTwoScore += 1
```

## Named Constants

This doesn't happen here ... or if it did happen, you've discovered the typo and fixed the code before posting it, but ... what would happen if instead of `"Scissors"` you had typed `"scissors"` or `"Scissor"`?  A comparison would have failed and ... the program would have a bug.  Tracking it down might be hard.

If instead you coded:

```
ROCK = "Rock"
PAPER = "Paper"
SCISSORS = "Scissors"

...

    hand_list = (ROCK, PAPER, SCISSOR)

...

    if pOnePick == SCISSORS:
        if pTwoPick == ROCK:
            ...
...
```

You run the code, and instead of a silent, hard to discover bug, you immediately get `NameError: name 'SCISSOR' is not defined`.  Tracking down the issue is much, much easier.

You might want to investigate the [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Enum).

Tip: You might also want named constants for `PLAYER`, `COMPUTER`, and `DRAW`.

Comment: > name = string makes a copy of the text in string.

This does not copy, but just creates an additional name for the same object. I am sure you know, but might surprise beginners if left uncorrected.

Comment: @mcocdawc You are technically correct … which is, of course, the best kind of correct.